# Nginx root(/) location proxy_pass not loading index.php

Tags: nginx

I am setting up two websites and both the websites are running on separate apache servers. 1 is mydomain.com and 2 is mydomain.com/abc/
mydomain.com is hosted on Server A 192.168.10.10
and mydomain.com/abc is hosted on Server B 192.168.10.11
, top of this I have set up one Nginx reverse proxy that has public IP.
**My Issue is** - I have set up one index.php under /var/www/html/index.php and in this php file I added one condition like if mydomain.com got hit outside from my country then it loads mydomain.com else it loads mydomain.com/abc and by using the below configuration my **index.php file is not loading** it directly redirecting to mydomain.com, I think I need to make changes in location / but what changes I don't know
looking for your help

my Nginx configuration

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php;
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

   location = / {
           root /var/www/html;
           index index.php;

           try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            proxy_pass http://192.168.10.10;
    }

    location /abc {
            index index.php;
            proxy_pass http://192.168.10.11:8080/abc/index.html;
            }

    location ~ \.php$ {
     include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
     fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you have both `try_files` and `proxy_pass`? And why is there a PHP location?

Comment: Hello Michael, Thanks for your reply... I thought try_files will call the index.php file but it didn’t worked, and about proxy_pass I have hosted mydomain.com/ and mydomain.com/abc both are hosted on different server so i don’t want to change the url.

Comment: now my index.php is loading properly but for / location, I am getting too may redirects

Answer (score 0):

below setting worked for me to load the index.php file but for / location I am getting 301 too many redirects.

```
    server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;

    location = / {
        rewrite ^ /index.php permanent;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://example.com:80;
    }

    location /abc {
        proxy_pass http://example.com:8080;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /var/www/html;
    }

    }
```